# NFA to DFA conversion confusion?

Tags: automata, dfa, nfa

I have this NFA in the book given:

[image: Example NFA]

And their solved DFA result was this:

[image: Resultant NFA]

But According to my solved solution (by finding e-closure of each state), it looks something like this:

```
    |  a   |  b  | c
----+----- +-----+---
ABD | CEBD |  Φ  | C
BD  | EBD  |  Φ  | C
C   |  Φ   | EBD | Φ
D   | EBD  |  Φ  | Φ
EBD | EBD  |  Φ  | C
CEBD| EBD  | EBD | C
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is identical to the DFA diagram, with two differences:

- Your table contains unreachable states (`BD`, `D`). Those are culled from the diagram.
- There is a misprint in the diagram. The two arrows between `{C}` and `{BDE}` have their labels switched. (The arrow going from `{C}` to `{BDE}` should be labeled `b`, and the arrow from `{BDE}` to `{C}` should be labeled `c`.)